# How to fix 'incompatible version' error when running JHipster Test with Maven and JDK 17?

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I created a project with JHipster and chose maven as the package manager.
I'm getting the following error when running the ./mvn:

[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.1.0:enforce (enforce-versions) @ j-hipster-test ---
[ERROR] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
You are running an incompatible version of Java. JHipster supports JDK 11 to 18.

I'm using JDK 17 which I have added into the Path variable of the System variables.
OS: Win 11
Node ver.18.16.0
JHipster ver. 7.9.3

Why is maven not picking up my JDK version?

I've tried installing JDK 11 and run the ./mvnw again but no luck.
I also added '"javaVersion": "17"' into JHipster's yo-rc.json file based on chatgpt's suggestion. (I know. I'm very frustrated and just want to get some quick answers).

I'm guessing that I need to change something in the pom.xml but I'm not very knowledgeable in working with maven.

"mvn -v" output:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.8 (4c87b05d9aedce574290d1acc98575ed5eb6cd39)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.8-bin\apache-maven-3.8.8
Java version: 1.8.0_371, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: What is the output of java -version?

Comment: Maven gets the Java tool chain from the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: java -version output:
java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224, mixed mode, sharing)

JAVA_HOME environment variable:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8

Comment: I just noticed that there are some missing dependency errors in the pom.xml:

Dependency 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.15.0' not found

Plugin 'io.github.git-commit-id:git-commit-id-maven-plugin:5.0.0' not found

Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.3.2' not found

Dependency org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:${project.version} not found

Comment: The JDK used by maven can be displayed by running `mvn -v` please paste output in your question. If version is correct then you could still modify `requireJavaVersion` element in `pom.xml`

Comment: So mvn -v showed that you are running Java 8 (1.8.0_371). It's not related to maven nor JHipster, your OS environment is wrong, you should fix it first.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that my path variable was wrong and have fixed it as @GaëlMarziou mentioned. How do I close this question?

Comment: You add an answer and you mark it as solution